# Removing a option from DropDownList item with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, html-select

I have a situation where in some cases a dropdownlist can contain a default value that is not selectable, once another value is changed, the default value should no longer be an option.  From what I can tell, this concept does not exist natively, so I am trying to code it up with jQuery.  All the DropDownLists which have this condition have a class 'valueSkippedHyperSwap' assigned to them.  the value that needs to be removed is the caret '^'.  Here is what I have, which is not working:

```
    $('.valueSkippedHyperSwap').change(function () {
        var node = $(this).has("value='^'");
        node.remove();
    });
```

per folks request, here is the HTML, though I cannot for the world in me figure out how to get it into a code block:

```
<!-- snip -->

<div class="questionItem">
<!-- snip -->
<select class="valueSkippedHyperSwap" id="answers_2__Answer" name="answers[2].Answer">
<option selected="selected" value="^">(^) Blank (skip pattern)</option>
<option value="0">(0) No</option>
<option value="1">(1) Yes</option>
<option value="-">(-) Not assessed</option>
</select></div>

<div class="questionItem">
<!-- snip -->
<select class="valueSkippedHyperSwap" id="answers_3__Answer" name="answers[3].Answer">
<option selected="selected" value="^">(^) Blank (skip pattern)</option>
<option value="0">(0) Clear speech-distinct intelligible words</option>
<option value="1">(1) Unclear speech-slurred or mumbled words</option>
<option value="2">(2) No speech-absence of spoken words</option>
<option value="-">(-) Not assessed</option>
</select></div>

<!-- snip -->
```

One of the key things to note here is that there is more than one input with the valueSkippedHyperSwap class name, so within the event, we have to use the $(this) to fine the correct option, cannot do another search.

Comment: First, I don't think the change event fires when the options of the select are changed, but when the selected item is changed. So unless whatever the user had previously selected disappears and causes something else to become selected, the change event won't fire

Comment: Second, GIVE US THE HTML! how do we know what element has the valuSkippedHyperSwap class, is it the `<option/>` or the `<select/>`?

Comment: Third, your `.has("value='^'")` should be more like `.has("[value='^']")`.   the brackets indicate that its an attribute you're looking for.

Comment: Fourth: I see you're using ASP. Lookout because an asyncPostBack could undo everything that your jquery code does.

Comment: As you can see in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wj57h/), the change event doesn't fire until you change the value yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is like this

```
<select id="dd" class="valueSkippedHyperSwap"> 
    <option value="^">None</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>    
</select>
```

The below script should remove item with value `^` if any other options are selected

```
$(function(){

    $('.valueSkippedHyperSwap').change(function () {
       var item=$(this);
      if(item.val()!="^")
      {
        item.find("option[value='^']").remove();
      }
    });            

});
```

JsFiddle Sample http://jsfiddle.net/He5gP/10/

Comment: Looks good, except there is more than one input with the valueSkippedHyperSwap class name, so within the event, we have to use the $(this) to fine the correct option, cannot do another search.

Comment: @SamCarleton: Since we are using the class selector, This code will work for any number of select/dropdowns with the specified css class.

Comment: I thought that since $(".valueSkippedHyperSwap option[value='^']").remove(); used the class type, it would remove the options with a value of ^ from ALL select's that had the valueSkippedHyperSwap class.  The $(this) is the option, correct?  So doesn't the remove need to simply start with $(this) move to the parent, then remove the one with the option value of ^? http://jsfiddle.net/He5gP/6/

Comment: @SamCarleton: You are correct. I wast thinking about the initial selector. YEa, You amy update that line with $(this);

Comment: @SamCarleton: I updated the answer. Here is an example  http://jsfiddle.net/He5gP/10/