# Removing a radio button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, html-select

The form has one or more groups of radio buttons on it.  It is possible for the value to start off with the value of ^.  Once another value is selected, ^ is no longer viable, so it's div needs to be hidden.  Here is the source and the html, along with a link to it in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RSNxS/

```
$(function(){

    $('.tristateRadio').bind("change", handleTristateRadioChange);

    function handleTristateRadioChange(e) {
        var button = $this;
        var id = button.id();

        $("#"+id).filter(
            function(){ this.value == "^"}
        ).parent().hide();
    }
});
```

html

```
$<div class="questionItem">
    <h3>C0900A</h3>
Staff asmt mental status: recall current season <br/>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_12__Answer" name="answers[12].Answer" type="radio" value="0" /> (0) Not checked (No)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_12__Answer" name="answers[12].Answer" type="radio" value="1" /> (1) Checked (Yes)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_12__Answer" name="answers[12].Answer" type="radio" value="-" /> (-) Not assessed</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input checked="checked" class="tristateRadio" id="answers_12__Answer" name="answers[12].Answer" type="radio" value="^" /> (^) Blank (skip pattern)</div>
</div>

<div class="questionItem">
    <h3>C0900B</h3>
Staff asmt mental status: recall location of room <br/>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_13__Answer" name="answers[13].Answer" type="radio" value="0" /> (0) Not checked (No)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_13__Answer" name="answers[13].Answer" type="radio" value="1" /> (1) Checked (Yes)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_13__Answer" name="answers[13].Answer" type="radio" value="-" /> (-) Not assessed</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input checked="checked" class="tristateRadio" id="answers_13__Answer" name="answers[13].Answer" type="radio" value="^" /> (^) Blank (skip pattern)</div>
</div>

<div class="questionItem">
    <h3>C0900C</h3>
Staff asmt mental status: recall staff names/faces <br/>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_14__Answer" name="answers[14].Answer" type="radio" value="0" /> (0) Not checked (No)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_14__Answer" name="answers[14].Answer" type="radio" value="1" /> (1) Checked (Yes)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_14__Answer" name="answers[14].Answer" type="radio" value="-" /> (-) Not assessed</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input checked="checked" class="tristateRadio" id="answers_14__Answer" name="answers[14].Answer" type="radio" value="^" /> (^) Blank (skip pattern)</div>
</div>

<div class="questionItem">
    <h3>C0900D</h3>
Staff asmt mental status: recall in nursing home <br/>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_15__Answer" name="answers[15].Answer" type="radio" value="0" /> (0) Not checked (No)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_15__Answer" name="answers[15].Answer" type="radio" value="1" /> (1) Checked (Yes)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_15__Answer" name="answers[15].Answer" type="radio" value="-" /> (-) Not assessed</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input checked="checked" class="tristateRadio" id="answers_15__Answer" name="answers[15].Answer" type="radio" value="^" /> (^) Blank (skip pattern)</div>
</div>

<div class="questionItem">
    <h3>C0900Z</h3>
Staff asmt mental status: none of above recalled <br/>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_16__Answer" name="answers[16].Answer" type="radio" value="0" /> (0) Not checked (No)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_16__Answer" name="answers[16].Answer" type="radio" value="1" /> (1) Checked (Yes)</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input class="tristateRadio" id="answers_16__Answer" name="answers[16].Answer" type="radio" value="-" /> (-) Not assessed</div>
        <div class="questionCheckbox"><input checked="checked" class="tristateRadio" id="answers_16__Answer" name="answers[16].Answer" type="radio" value="^" /> (^) Blank (skip pattern)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting this on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Is this not similar to your last question? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005071/removing-a-option-from-dropdownlist-item-with-jquery)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid you have multiple duplicate id's for element, id attribute should always be unique. Other then that please be clear what you are asking, its hard to understand, I am happy to help you out, cheers!

Comment: Html Validator: (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) Don't get the unexpected result and then blame the browser which it is not working on, make sure your Html is valid first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely fix the multiple id issues, which is invalid HTML and could cause undesired and unexpected behaviour (as others have already mentioned).

However the following does not use selection by id and will hide the **last** `<input>` with value = `^` in a group, when any of the other siblings are changed:

```
$('.tristateRadio').bind('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings(':last').hide();
});
```

The original code in the question is not working because `$this` is undefined. I think you probably meant `$(this)` in order to wrap the native object in jQuery. These sorts of errors are usually shown in the browser's console or in an dialog and are the first place to look when debugging JavaScript.

Comment: That is perfect, it did not dawn on me that the ^ is really always the last one, which it is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

your code is all kinds of broken:

- there is no implicit `$this` variable
- there is no `.id()` function
- you dont need to filter a jquery object selected with the id selector when you can just use an if statement
- as someone else pointed out, DOM ids must be unique, so had i left that id selector you had in your code, it would select the incorrect element 2/3 of the time.
- there is no need to reselect the current element in the event handler when the current element is `this`
- nitpick: prefix variables that are jquery objects with `$` for readability

edit: 
my code sucks, i leave you just the comments

Comment: "Once another value is selected, ^ is no longer viable, so it's div needs to be hidden." - because you didn't understand the question, and therefore, couldn't answer it.

Comment: I think OP is asking for ^ to be removed when you select an option other than ^. Not when you re-select ^.

Comment: ah good call. will fix, but i think that writing good code might benefit him more then hiding the right dom element.

Comment: Now it is removing the `other` option you click on, instead of `^`. Remove the sibling with `^` not `$(this)`

Comment: @mkoryak: Your code doesn't suck. To be honest, I think the Html in the original code is such a mess there is a lot of issues to fix before this will work reliably.

Comment: Well it says on the upvote icon "This answer is useful". +1 This answer is very useful and full of good advise too.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the id's.  It seems that it is a bug in ASP.Net MVC that all the radio buttons with the same name, get the same id.  One must manually set the id attribute, go figure:)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because there can only be ONE `id` on a page. jQuery assumes this, and will only select one of your radio buttons, therefore never finding any with the value '^'.

Simply change it to a class and it will work (or use some other kind of identification - like `name`)

```
$("."+theClass).filter(
    function(){ this.value == "^"}
).parent().hide();
```

You may also choose to use CSS selectors:

```
$("."+theClass+"[value='^']").parent().hide();
```